# To which Debian package does /etc/nsswitch.conf belong?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, package-management, nsswitch

I tried to find out to which package `/etc/nsswitch.conf` belongs on my Debian machine, but `dpkg --search /etc/nsswitch.conf` won't tell me. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This file belongs to the **base-files** package.
You can use the following apt-file command to see to which package a file belongs:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search nsswitch.conf
```

Check debian README files for explanation about some files in base-files package

```
cat /usr/share/doc/base-files/README
```

> Q. After upgrading my system recently, I noticed that some files from
>   base-files do not match the ones which are installed on a fresh install
>   of squeeze. Should I not be warned about that?
>
> A. Those files are configuration files, so they are completely under
>   the control of the system admin. The files installed by base-files are
>   just defaults. Changes in the default files are not important enough
>   to warn the user, as it is also policy that prompting should be
>   reduced to a minimum. This is also the reason they are not handled via
>   dpkg's conffile mechanism.

In either case, if you want to "upgrade" those files, just look at the
postinst for base-files (i.e. /var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst)
and you will see how they are created and where their master copies are:

```
install_from_default /usr/share/base-files/nsswitch.conf /etc/nsswitch.conf
install_from_default /usr/share/base-files/dot.profile   /root/.profile
install_from_default /usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc    /root/.bashrc
install_from_default /usr/share/base-files/profile       /etc/profile
install_from_default /usr/share/base-files/motd          /etc/motd
```

So, if you want your system to be as similar as possible to a newly
installed squeeze system, you might want to sync these files manually.

Answer (score 6):

`dpkg --search` do not show `/etc/nsswitch.conf` because it is not registered as *conffile* so it is a bit of a special case. For example `dpkg -S /etc/deluser.conf` can be used to identify package that owns `/etc/deluser.conf` file.
With path omitted `dpkg --search nsswitch.conf` actually show results.

I also like [dlocate](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/dlocate) utility which is very helpful to find which package owns a file. `dlocate` is a faster alternative to `dpkg -S`.

`apt-file` is most useful to search for files in non-installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

```
File                                    Packages
/usr/share/base-files/nsswitch.conf     base-files
```

I got this from https://packages.debian.org/index and searched under "contents"

Answer (score 0):

Some fine answers here already, to which I only have a little to add, though too much, it seems, for a comment:

For me, four packages appear to have their fingers in this pie:

```
martind@swiftboat:~$ grep -l /etc/nsswitch.conf /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnss-mdns:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libnss-myhostname:amd64.postinst
martind@swiftboat:~$
```

base-files offers more than libc-bin:

```
martind@swiftboat:~$ diff /usr/share/{libc-bin,base-files}/nsswitch.conf
9a10
> gshadow:        files
martind@swiftboat:~$
```

libnss-mdns adds mdns to the hosts line.  libnss-myhostname adds myhostname there, with the potential promise to remove the need for /etc/hosts, if only that weren't [the recommended way](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/hostname/dnsdomainname.1.en.html) to get hostname --fqdn to work.